# Prediction analysis (Time series model) in UNIX

Tags: r, algorithm, perl, bash, prediction

I know its not a code level question but wanted your views.

I need to perform “**Prediction Analysis**” in UNIX level using **Time series model** (like **ARIMA**).

We have implemented the same using R , but my work environment is not supporting R.

**Data snapshot**

```
Year | Month| Data1| Data2 | Data3
2012 | Jan | 1 |1 |3
2012 | Feb | 2 |21 | 4
```

So I wanted to implement some algorithm which will help me in finding the predicted values for future months.

Is there any other way of implementing “**Time series Prediction Analysis**” in UNIX (preferably Perl/Shell).

Comment: If your environment supports Python, you could use StatsModels Package: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/tsa.html

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~janert/Math-HoltWinters-0.03/lib/Math/HoltWinters.pm ?

Comment: R is available for unix platforms.

Comment: @Rob In my work environment (UNIX box) .. R is not installed ... at home i have implemented the same algo in R

Comment: @mpapec Thanks ... I will work on it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in `perl` and statistics, I'm sure you are aware of [`PDL`](http://pdl.perl.org).  There are some [specific time-series statistics modules](https://metacpan.org/release/PDL-Stats) available and of course, since `perl` is involved, other CPAN modules can be used.

`R` is still king and has a lot of packages to choose from - and, lucky us, R and `perl`  play nice together using [`Statistics::R`](https://metacpan.org/release/Statistics-R).  I've not tried using `Statistics-R` from the `PDL` shell but this too may be possible to some extent.

Here's a `pdl` example session using `MVA`

```
/home/zombiepl % pdl
pdl> use Statistics::MVA::MultipleRegression;

pdl> $lol = [ [qw/745 36 66/],
              [qw/895 37 68/],
              [qw/442 47 64/],
              [qw/440 32 53/],
              [qw/1598 1 101/],];

pdl> linear_regression($lol);

The coefficients are: B[0] = -281.426985090045, B[1] = -7.61102966577879, 
B[2] = 19.0102910918022.
R^2 is 0.943907302962818
```

Cheers and good luck with your project.